# How to achieve calendar week view in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How can I achieve week view of the calendar in my iOS app as shown below,  ideally using Apple calendar components (if any) and also how can I retrieve the selected date.

I have tried using both [FSCalender](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and [CVCalender](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) plugins, without much success, as each was missing one element or the other.

[image]

Comment: When you say "weekView" do you mean the table view showing the times at the bottom?

Comment: No, I can do the table view with the times, but I want to get the week view as shown in the top of the image.

Comment: Ok. Then you are asking about create calendaView. Apple Does not provide one out of the box, so you will have to create your own. Or, you can use ones already created by people. Maybe you can use the one I created by clicking [HERE](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar). If you need help setting it up, then just open An issue on the repository. I check my issues every 1-2 hours. But, I have documented it pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, you lay out a bunch of views and set their contents. Perhaps use a collection view for the horizontal days. Definitely use a table view for the times. There's nothing in the public SDK to do it all for you. You just put together a view hierarchy the normal way.